# How can I get rid of this error: error: unreported exception FileNotFoundException;

Tags: java, arrays, file

Here's my code. I have to write it without using the FileNotFoundException class. The code reads from a file which contains array info. I get the this error:

```
F:\FanClub.java:59: error: unreported exception FileNotFoundException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
    Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);
```

Thanks

```
import java.util.Scanner;               
import java.util.ArrayList;

import java.io.*;

public class FanClub
{
    private static Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        final int NUM_FANS = 100;
        int numFans = 0;
        int[] ages = new int[NUM_FANS];

        String[] names = new String[NUM_FANS];

        numFans = fillArrays(names, ages, NUM_FANS);
    }

    public static int fillArrays(String[] names, int[] ages, int NUM_FANS)
    {
        int counter = 0;
        System.out.print("Enter the file name: ");
        String fileName = keyboard.nextLine();

        File file = new File(fileName);
        Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);

        if (!file.exists())
        {
            System.out.println("File " + fileName + " not found.");
            System.exit(0);
        }

        int[] numFans = new int[NUM_FANS];

        while (inputFile.hasNext() && counter < numFans.length)
        {
            numFans[counter] = inputFile.nextInt();
            counter++;
        }
        inputFile.close();
        return counter;
    }
}
```

Comment: Uh, find the file?  (Which is line 59?)

Comment: @HotLicks I don't think this is the issue. The OP is not declaring the `FileNotFoundException` in the method and this is causing a compile time error.

Comment: See this [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/) and especially the "Catch Or Specify Requirement" section.

Comment: Add `throws IOException` (preferrably `throws FileNotFoundException`) to the end of your fillArrays method signature, like you've done with your main method.

Comment: No reason. I get the same error whether ask before or after creating the Scanner.

Comment: @sbat It throws the exception whether the file name entered is found or not.

Comment: @sbat How will that help him solve his problem?

Comment: Enter the file name: fandata.txt
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
        at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:909)
        at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1530)
        at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2160)
        at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2119)
        at FanClub.fillArrays(FanClub.java:61)
        at FanClub.main(FanClub.java:33)
Press any key to continue . . .

Comment: @JoshM Because then it'll actually compile...

Comment: I'm trying not to cheat the compiler. I've already put in the test code that would stop the program if the file name isn't found.

Comment: @DennisMello I imagine the file you're giving it has things other than integers in it, in which case you should be reading those first. Also, `hasNext()` will tell you whether the scanner has another token, not specifically whether it has another int, `hasNextInt()` does that. If you want more help, show us what's inside your text file.

Comment: @DennisMello I know, I was just answering Josh's question. By the way, your code to stop the program if the file isn't found is only effective if you put it _before_ you create the `inputFile` scanner object.

Comment: Ok, so I swapped the position of the inputFile scanner and I'm still getting the same error 

'if (!file.exists())
  {
   System.out.println("File " + fileName + " not found.");
   System.exit(0);
  }

  Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);
'

Comment: Post the contents of your text file, I don't think you're reading it properly.

Comment: I will post it below, however I'm not sure the contents of the file that the user specifies would affect whether the program compiles without the error.

Comment: Chris P. Cream
5
Scott Free
9
Lou Tenant
3
Trish Fish
12
Ella Mentry
4
Holly Day
3
Robyn DeCradle
12
Annette Funicello
4
Elmo
7
Grover
3
Big Bird
9
Bert
7
Ernie
3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I tried to explain in the comments, you're reading the file in the wrong order. You say your file looks like this:

```
Chris P. Cream 5 Scott Free 9 Lou Tenant 3 Trish Fish 12 Ella Mentry 4 Holly Day 3 Robyn DeCradle 12 Annette Funicello 4 Elmo 7 Grover 3 Big Bird 9 Bert 7 Ernie 3
```

You're just calling `inputFile.nextInt()`, which attempts to read an int, but `"Chris P. Cream"` is *not* an int, which is why you're getting that input mismatch exception. So first you need to read the name, then you can read that number.

Now, since it isn't clear how your text file is delimited (it's all on one line), this presents a problem because the names can be one, two, or even three words, and are followed by a number. You can still do this, but you'll need a regular expression that tells it to read up to that number.

```
while (inputFile.hasNext() && counter < numFans.length)
{
    names[counter] = inputFile.findInLine("[^\\d]*").trim();
    numFans[counter] = inputFile.nextInt();
    System.out.println(names[counter] + ": " + numFans[counter]);
    counter++;
}
```

However, if your file is actually formatted like this (separate lines):

```
Chris P. Cream 
5 
Scott Free 
9 
Lou Tenant 
3 
Trish Fish 
12 
Ella Mentry 
4 
Holly Day 
3 
Robyn DeCradle 
12 
Annette Funicello 
4 
Elmo 
7 
Grover 
3 
Big Bird 
9 
Bert 
7 
Ernie 
3
```

Then you're in luck, because you can do this instead (doesn't require a regular expression):

```
while (inputFile.hasNext() && counter < numFans.length)
{
    names[counter] = inputFile.nextLine();
    numFans[counter] = inputFile.nextInt();
    if (inputFile.hasNext())
        inputFile.nextLine(); // nextInt() will read a number, but not the newline after it
    System.out.println(names[counter] + ": " + numFans[counter]);
    counter++;
}
```

What did Ernie say when Bert asked if he wanted icecream?

Sure Bert.

Comment: He can follow all of your advise but will still get the same error. Unreported exception errors are at **compile time**. The problems you are addressing is at runtime.

Comment: @DanielLerps Read our comments on the question, we're already past that point.

Comment: @sbat Throwing the exception is not a good solution though. Exceptions are made to be handled and not to crash the program.

Comment: @DanielLerps That's not always true though. Most API's throw or catch and rethrow exceptions (not that this is an API, I'm just saying that it has its uses). Plus they tend to get in the way of simple applications like this. I suggested throwing the exception because I made the assumption that the OP is either just starting out or is taking a class and probably hasn't talked about error handling yet. If I really wanted to nitpick I'd say you should also include a finally block and close that scanner in it, or better yet use a try-with-resources block.

Comment: @sbat Exceptions are usually thrown, re-thrown or attached to other exceptions if the place is not the right one where it should be handled or if they are not specific enough. In this case it is exactly the right place where it should be handled... I think encouraging a beginner to discard exception because they are uncomfortable to deal with just leads to bad programming habits.

Comment: @sbat Thanks! Your second set of code is what did it. The file data is separated like you show above but I'm still trying to learn how to format my comments. I had to move the scanner object to after the loop and add 'throws IOException' to the method header. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this instead:

```
File file = null;

try
{
    file = new File(fileName);
    Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);
}
catch(IOException ioe) // should actually catch FileNotFoundException instead
{
    System.out.println("File " + fileName + " not found.");
    System.exit(0);
}
```

Comment: I have to make this work without using the FileNotFoundException class

Comment: Well, the constructor call `new Scanner(File)` will always throw that Exception... therefore there is no way around that. [Java API: Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#Scanner(java.io.File))

Comment: If you do not catch it or throw it, your program will not compile. If you throw it, your program will crash as soon as an invalid filename is entered. Without catching it, a following if-statement is never reached because the code termination in the method stops... You can catch an `IOException` if that makes you feel better, but it basically does not change anything. See the update for that!